# How to save ImageView image? (Android)

Tags: android, image, imageview, save

I'm creating my first Android application. I have an ImageView that's used to contain an image taken by the camera.

I created a save button, that triggers an onClick event that's supposed to save the image to memory.

I have tried over and over again with countless methods, taken from other questions about this on Stackoverflow, but the app always crashes and the image does not get saved.

Anyone can help?

## EDIT:

It's alright, it finally worked. I used samkirton's code (https://gist.github.com/samkirton/0242ba81d7ca00b475b9), and it worked.

Comment: Showing what you've done will make it easier to answer your question.

Comment: There is no ImageView in that code. Please post the logcat. Tell which exceptions you have.

Comment: @greenapps I edited my question and included another code that I have tried. I will post the logcat in a minute.

Comment: `cachePath.createNewFile();` Better remove that line as it serves nothing.

Comment: `I forgot to send a View argument to the onClick method.` ???? Please post complete code. And post the logcat! POST THE LOGCAT!

Comment: @greenapps It finally worked. I used this code https://gist.github.com/samkirton/0242ba81d7ca00b475b9.